# using scanf to parse hh:mm:ss, strange error with some inputs

Tags: c, parsing, time, scanf

The following code is used to parse times like 07:04:51:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int hh, mm, ss;
    scanf("%i:%i:%i\n", &hh, &mm, &ss);
    printf("%i:%i:%i\n", hh, mm, ss);
}
```

Some times can be parsed and other ones don't:

```
$ echo 07:04:51 | ./test.exe 
7:4:51
$ echo 08:04:51 | ./test.exe 
0:0:32767
$ echo 09:04:51 | ./test.exe 
0:0:32766
$ echo 10:04:51 | ./test.exe 
10:4:51
$ echo 11:09:10 | ./test.exe 
11:0:32764
```

What is the reason?

[ideone](https://ideone.com/2ksrkx)

Comment: ... and check the return value of scanf, or you won't see errors.

Comment: @user3121023: you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it would be better to use %d instead of %i. With %i, if the value has a leading zero, the value will be read as an octal value (base 8). 08 and 09 are not valid octal values.
scanf will return the number of items successfully scanned. use

```
if ( scanf("%d:%d:%d", &hh, &mm, &ss) == 3)
```

to verify that three items were scanned.